# Javascript driven forms in Django

Tags: javascript, django, validation, django-forms

Django uses his [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/) API for input validation. The form is sent to the template, and it is rendered as an html ([as_p and friends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#as-p)).

When the user is ready, he `POST` the form, the data is validated, and the form is re-rendered on the template if it is not valid.

This is odd when the form is not valid just because lack of enough caracteres (i.e. min_length) on a field or invalid characters: one POST too much just to tell the user it is missing something very basic.

So, is there any available way (Django or app) of rendering a form with javascript code that "tests"[*] some of the form' fields on the client-side? I.e. have a form which is rendered `as_javascript(...)` that dynamically shows error messages that would be shown by form.errors?

This should not work for all fields because some require a database hit, but it should work on simple (and most common) fields, namely CharField, TextField, etc.

[*] "tests" because validation has always to be made also on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to validate something in JS before submitting. Here's one way to do that.
Instead of putting an input of type submit in the form you should put a button of type button:

```
<form id="my-form" submit="...">
  ...        
  <input type='button' id='submit-button' value="Save">
</form>
```

Note that unless you specify the type as "button", it will still try to submit.

Then in a JS file you write something like this (include jQuery in your HTML file):

```
$('#submit-button').click(function() {
  var errors = testErrors(); // this function tests for the errors.
  if (errors != "") {
    alert(errors);
  } else {
    $('#my-form').submit();
  }
}
```

Example testErrors():

```
function testErrors() {
    var country         = $("#id_country").val();
    var city            = $("#id_city").val();

    var errors = "";
    if (country == "") {
        errors += "- Please select a country\n";
    }
    if (city.length <= 10 ) {
        errors += "- Your city name is too short\n";
    }
    return errors;
}
```

So in testErrors you define your own tests for each field. In this example there are two, country and city. For country the code tests whether it's blank and for city whether it's longer than 10 characters. You can define further tests of your own. Please refer to jQuery documentation as well on how to retrieve values from different types of form fields.

Comment: That is equivalent to what I said I wanted to avoid: "one POST too much just to tell the user it is missing something very basic". What I'm looking as a way of actually *render* the form with the javascript code with the errors messages.

Comment: I'm not sure you read the JS part carefully. It tests for errors defined by yourself in testErrors() before submitting and if there are none, executes the .submit() command. I don't know how to get the server-side error messages integrated into the form before submitting nor if it's possible.

The only extra work here is that you'd have to create tests for each field in JS code, but that should be completely trivial with jQuery selectors and again, the user would find out about errors before submitting.

Comment: "but that should be completely trivial with jQuery selectors" I'm sorry but I'm not seeing why it is trivial. My question is exactly about that "trivial" part, not the click and submit JQuery functionality.

Comment: I've edited my answer now. My apologies if the previous comment came across as arrogant. In any case, I don't think you can create Django forms with embedded JS. At least not in a way that's easier than what I've just shown. If this gets you there, please accept the answer.

Comment: thanks, I was aware of that solution. I'm trying see if anyone knows of any implementation that abstracts from having to code the JS as you are showing, i.e. make the form generate it itself.